# How to use a library writtein in TypeScript 2.6 in a project that uses TS 2.2

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have an existing project that is written in TypeScript 2.2.
Now, I need to include an external library, written in TypeScript 2.6.

The project compilation fails, when I import a class from that external library.

If I try to use any functions from the external class, I get an error saying e.g 
"Supplied parameters don't match function signature" ( they do )

If I upgrade my TS to 2.6 it will break the whole project.

Is there a way to compile/downgrade 2.6 into 2.2 or use 2 separate compilers, one for the project(excluding the library which uses 2.6 ) and another compiler for that library.

Answer (score 1):

Use `"skipLibCheck": true` option in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't upgrade to the newer version of TypeScript, you should instead depend on the JavaScript and Type Definition for the external library.

The recommended way to package TypeScript (i.e. for NPM) is to include just the `.js` and the `.d.ts` files, but if you have found a library that doesn't do it that way, you could generate it yourself by compiling it with the `--declaration` flag, example tsconfig option shown below.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true
}
```

By not including the original TypeScript file in your program, you won't depend on any specific language feature from that library.